# Electron use Barcode Scanner when app is in background

Tags: javascript, electron, keyboard-shortcuts, barcode-scanner, keydown

I've got an Electron app and a barcode-scanner which just gives the scanned input like a keyboard. So I can use events like `textInput` which just works fine. 
But I also want my app to react to the input if the app has no focus.

I found something like `global shortcuts`:

```
   app.on('ready', () => {
    // Register a 'CommandOrControl+X' shortcut listener.
    const ret = globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+X', () => {
      console.log('CommandOrControl+X is pressed')
    })

    if (!ret) {
      console.log('registration failed')
    }

    // Check whether a shortcut is registered.
    console.log(globalShortcut.isRegistered('CommandOrControl+X'))
  })
```

But I can't define a `global shortcut` for the scanned codes. For example the scanner gives me the input `43324`. It isn't possible to define a `global shortcut` for this.

Another idea was to scan a code which triggers the `windows keyboard key + 1` because this would bring the first application in the taskbar to the foreground but it doesn't work too and is also kinda dirty and impractical solution.

Is there any other way to accomplish this task?

Comment: As far as I can tell you **can't** do that directly through electron, you need to create your own (native) wrappers. Besides, consider that you should handle a timeout or so, since the keyboard event from a Barcode Scanner is not unique, it triggers an event for each input character, so be aware of that as well. What I did in my previous application was listening (globally) to the window's keydown event, and, using a timeout, I gathered the entire barcode and retrieved it. However, this does not address the issue that it should work when the app is in background.

Comment: Maybe, you can take a look at this instead: https://github.com/WilixLead/iohook . Listen to a generic keyboard event in electron's MAIN thread, then trigger the renderer through the IPC to accomplish what you actually need.